# Schedule a cron job ev X minutes, but exclude it from certain hours in the morning?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Is it possible to make a cron job run say, every 20 minutes, but make it not run for say, 1-4 in the morning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is.

0,20,40 0,5-23 * * * /job/to/run

Comment: Might want `0,4-23` there depending on whether you want it to not happen until the end of 4 or at the beginning.

Comment: Might want to add 'refer to the man page`: http://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you need more specific or complicated rules that can't be covered by the version of cron you're using, you can always write a small shellscript wrapper which will check the date +%H or other relevant statuses.